# Multiple advanced filter using a combobox and a textbox with Excel 2003 VBA

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, excel-2003

I searched the topics carefully before I post my question and could not actually find a match for my case.

I have created a large database for the needs of my current job using Excel 2003. I have established an Advanced Filter with eight possible criteria options. Now I have to expand the interface and functionality by setting up a UserForm. Unfortunately, I feel if I don't finish this it can cost me my job.

The purpose of my UserForm is to ease the search in the database by allowing the user to specify a criteria from three dropboxes (cboSelectCategory, cboSelectStructure, cboSelectSX). The combobox cboSelectCategory is accommodating the heads of my criteria range which is CriteriaCategory (see figure 1). The other two, cboSelectStructure and cboSelectSX are populated from two separate dropdown lists which every piece of information in the database has both (in my database every single row stands for a document and I have three sheets of documents - active documents, cancelled documents and pending documents). All three cbo's should be using one and the same textbox (txtSearch) for entering the search keyword/s. And also, if nothing is selected from the cbo's, the textbox input text should serve as a search string throughout the entire database matching data even partially (no mater if data begins or ends with the search string symbols).

Here is what my code looks like so far. I've added comments and links to pictures to illustrate my case.

[image: Overview of the criteria range called CriteriaCategory]

The range CriteriaCategory includes the headers of the columns BN to BU (DOC NUMBER, NAME IN ENGLISH, including STRUCTURE). The cells below them (row nr. 8) are used to enter the search string depending on the type of data I am searching for. For example, if I'm looking for the document number, I'll be typing a search string in the cell just below DOC NUMBER and so on. These headers are listed in my cboSelectCategory combobox in the UserForm on the picture below.

[image: UserForm appearance with naming conventions]

I am trying to make Excel put whatever I type in the keyword textbox in the correct cell in the worksheet depending on what I have chosen in cboSelectCategory and then run the advanced filter. Furthermore I need to make Excel search the entire database if the three cbo's are left blank by the user and return every match, no matter where on the worksheets (I have three) it is found and no matter if it is in the beginning of the cell text or at the end.

I haven't got a slightest clue how to tackle this situation. Any ideas are appreciated, code snippets too. Mine looks like this:

```
   Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()

        If Me.cboSelectCategory.Value = "" Or Me.cboSelectStructure.Value = "" Or Me.cboSelectSX.Value = "" Then
            Me.txtSearch.Value = Sheet6.Cells("BS8").Value

            AdvancedFilterCategory

        Else
            Me.cboSelectCategory.Value = Range("CriteriaCategoryFirstRow").Find(what:=Me.cboSelectCategory.Value, _
            LookIn:=xlValues)
            Me.txtSearch.Value = Range("CriteriaCategoryFirstRow").Offset(1, 0).Value

            AdvancedFilterCategory

        End If

    End Sub
```

My idea using the range CriteriaCategoryFirstRow (the name is a hint) was to make Excel search the first row of the CriteriaCategory range to find a match of the cboSelectCategory value and then go one cell down, put the value from the keyword textbox (txtSearch) and execute the advanced filter. Unfortunately, this doesn't work and I think my idea may be just wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I totally understand your issue per se; however if you are trying to return records from a database I'd recommend dynamically building a SQL string based on the form values entered.

Here's some sample code connecting to an Access Database, and selecting some data based on Excel cells being filled out:

```
Const adCmdText = &H1
Public Sub Example()

Dim DbConnection               As Object
Dim AccessRecordSet            As Object

Set DbConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set AccessRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Set DbConnection = New ADODB.Connection

'Lookup your relevant Connection String Online
'www.connectionstrings.com :)
With DbConnection
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source='C:\Users\SampleUserName\Desktop\MYDATABASE.accdb'; Persist Security Info=False;"
    .Open
End With

'To Customize your SQL I'd do something like...
'I'm assuming all ANDs; hopefully this is illustrative enough to communicate the general idea
SqlWhere = "Where "


If Range("A1").Value <> "" Then
    SqlWhere = SqlWhere & "[MyTableName].[MyFieldName] = " & Range("A1").Value & " AND " 'Add apostrophes on either side of the double quotes if the variable is TEXT
End If

If Range("B1").Value <> "" Then
    SqlWhere = SqlWhere & "[MyTableName].[MyOtherField] = " & Range("B1").Value & " AND "
End If

StrSql = "SELECT * FROM [MyTableName] "

'Remove the last AND applicable
If SqlWhere = "Where " Then
    SqlWhere = ""
Else
    SqlWhere = Left(SqlWhere, Len(SqlWhere) - 4)
End If

StrSql = StrSql & SqlWhere

AccessRecordSet.Open StrSql, DbConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

'This will paste the recordset to range you specify below
Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset AccessRecordSet

MsgBox "There are " & AccessRecordSet.RecordCount & " record(s)!"

End Sub
```

Hopefully this is illustrative of how to build a dynamic SQL string. You can use that to power your query and return the relevant results you are after. You can even do SQL queries in Excel if you already have the data loaded there, just look up the relevant connection string.

Hopefully this helps

==Ryan

Comment: It would be even harder for me to deal with MS Access 2003 and have two separate (although linked) files. Furthermore I've come up with VBA password protection for the Excel workbook and I don't want to loose that functionality.